# How to delete a system file from an Android App?

Tags: android, shell, system

I'm using [Root Tools](http://code.google.com/p/roottools/downloads/list) and I'm not getting too far with it...
I want to have access to delete files from /system/app and other directories that require root. I would love to do it programmatically through Java, but if I can do it through shell commands, that's OK. Too. My phone is rooted. Here's what I've tried so far.

```
RootTools.remount("/system", "rw");
                 try {
                    RootTools.sendShell("rm /system/app/Videos.apk", -1);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (RootToolsException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (TimeoutException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
```

I've also tried:

```
 public static void sendShell(List<String> cmds) throws Exception {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());

        for (String tmpCmd : cmds) {
                os.writeBytes(tmpCmd+"\n");
        }

        os.writeBytes("exit\n");
        os.flush();
        os.close();

        process.waitFor();
    }
```

I have no idea what to do from here...

Comment: your code seems legit . do you have the super-user app installed on your device? it should show a dialog as soon as you execute the "su" command.

Comment: The SuperUser app is installed and it does pop up. I have an issue with the system being mounted as rw... I think it's the ROM even though it's stock rooted...

Comment: that's an important thing to write. you should have written it in the question , to know at which phase you have the problem.

Comment: Didnt know that at the time of writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our conversations it looks like you need a different rom as there were issues remounting partitions on your device.

I would bet that flashing a new rom would alleviate this issue and allow RootTools to properly remount /system as rw and allow you to delete your file.

Comment: I tried flashing a new ROM and it worked. For some reason, the stock ICS didnt work, so I downgraded to the stock GB. Everything works fine. Thanks!

Comment: System is remounting fine, I'm able to delete files from other explorer apps, but when I run new File("/system/app/file1").delete() it returns false, and when I run RootTools.sendShell("rm /system/app/file1") the file remains... Any ideas on why?

Comment: Cant seem to format this, but Here's the code. Hope this helps. 
    RootTools.remount("/system", "rw");
  this.sendShell("rm /system/app/file1");
  Log.e("Proc - Uninstall", new File("/system/app/file1").delete() + "");
  for (String file : this.fileList) {
   new File(file).delete();

Comment: first, the .delete returns false because your application does not have permission to delete that file. You need root to do what you want. 

Secondly, you need to log the result coming back the sendshell. What's the output? It could be that system is mounted as RW, it could be that rm doesn't exist or isn't in your PATH, it could be that rm is present but is corrupted.

There could be many reasons why rm isn't working, but you need to see what the error is.

Comment: 06-26 11:14:06.751: E/RootTools -  SendShell(3661): rm failed for /system/app/file1, No such file or directory
06-26 11:14:06.751: E/RootTools -  SendShell(3661): 255
06-26 11:14:06.751: E/Proc - Uninstall(3661): false
06-26 11:14:06.751: E/Proc - Uninstall(3661): system/app/File1 not deleted

I verified that the file was there and it was...

Comment: That's a system error, if your getting that then the file doesn't exist at that path. Do ls /system/app/file1 what does it return?

Comment: Also, my app requests root using RootTools... does that make a difference?